langchain: Using ainvoke while invoking a chain gives error
I'm trying to use ainvoke while making my function asynchronous.
async def get_result(template, user_question):
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
    model = mixtral_llm
    sql_response = (
        RunnablePassthrough.assign(schema=get_schema)
        | prompt
        | model.bind(stop=["Question"])
        | StrOutputParser()
    )
    sql_query = await sql_response.ainvoke({"question":user_question})

But getting the error:
sql_query = await sql_response.ainvoke({"question":user_question})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 2536, in ainvoke
    input = await step.ainvoke(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/base.py", line 4537, in ainvoke
    return await self.bound.ainvoke(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 299, in ainvoke
    llm_result = await self.agenerate_prompt(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 643, in agenerate_prompt
    return await self.agenerate(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 1018, in agenerate
    output = await self._agenerate_helper(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 882, in _agenerate_helper
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 866, in _agenerate_helper
    await self._agenerate(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 1336, in _agenerate
    await self._acall(prompt, stop=stop, run_manager=run_manager, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 1295, in _acall
    return await run_in_executor(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain_core/runnables/config.py", line 514, in run_in_executor
    return await asyncio.get_running_loop().run_in_executor(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: _call() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

I tried changing the version of langchain-core, but I got the same error.
I'm running this code in following setup:

python3.9 amd64
langchain==0.1.0
langchain-core==0.1.23


waht is the value of get_schema ?
